# Android - Save video internal storage and playback

Tags: android

I have saved the sample mp4 video in android internal storage in a file, But when try to read from file and playback in android videoview by parsing file path as a uri , am getting can't play this video error. I had checked many links but no use, How do i implement this.?

```
final String mFileName = "sample.mp4";
try{
        FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = openFileOutput(mFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        mFileOutputStream.write(getResources().getAssets().open("sample_video.mp4").read());
        mFileOutputStream.close();
        Log.v(TAG, "Success");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/sample.mp4");
    mVideoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can't. `VideoView` internally uses a `MediaPlayer`, which explicitly [requires a file to be world-readable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)) (app's dirs aren't). The only way to bypass this limitation, as doc says, is to pass a File descriptor rather than the file path.

Unfortunately `VideoView` does not have a method like `setDataSource(FileDescriptor)`, so you have two ways:

1. Access the `VideoView`'s `MediaPlayer` [through reflection](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/widget/VideoView.java#VideoView.0mMediaPlayer) and call [`setDataSource(FileDescriptor)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)) on it. Not sure if this is a feasible solution, because the internal media player is instantiated when you call `VideoView.setVideoPath`, but you should not call it... in short, evaluate it, but it may be a dead end.
2. Use a `MediaPlayer`, [set a surface holder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)) on which play the video and pass a `FileDescriptor` directly to the `MediaPlayer` (imo this second solution is cleaner).

Comment: Is it possible by using content provider..?

Comment: It should be possible, by passing the content URI (`VideoView.setVideoURI()`). Just don't pass a uri such as `file://`, if so the internal `MediaPlayer` will simply call `setDataSource(String filepath)`.

Comment: can you elaborate more , How do i put file path in ContentProvider and how do i pass uri for videoview

Comment: Please read about `FileProvider`s on how to create a content provider to provide files. It is not difficult, but the explanation is long and the doc about this argument is really well done: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: But before creating a content provider I'd suggest you to try other solutions, such as the `ExoMedia` library, which internally uses ExoPlayer rather than MediaPlayer. https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia