# Open a video in the internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, loopj

I use a WS to download videos in my app.
After I want to open the downloaded video.

The problem is when I want to open the video I have this error :

```
VideoView: Unable to open content: /data/user/0/code.package/files/diapos/1.mp4
java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
```

This is the download function :

```
MyRestClient.get("/diapos/1", null, new BinaryHttpResponseHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] binaryData) {
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryData);
    try {
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/diapos/1.mp4");
        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
     } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

This is how I play the video :

```
final VideoView video = (VideoView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video);
String path = getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/diapos/1.mp4";
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
video.start();
```

Maybe it's not the good path ? Or the way I save the video ?
I specify than the video have to be downloaded in the internal storage. There is not external storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It work with the Internal Storage.
I use a FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler instead.

This is where I do my call of WS :

```
File file = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("movie.mp4");

        Client.TESTVIDEOget(null, new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(file) {

            @Override public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File file) {
                Log.d("debug", "success : " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n size : " + file.length());
            }

            @Override public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {
                Log.d("debug", "fail : " + file.getAbsolutePath());

            }
        });
```

This is where I play the movie :

```
final VideoView video = (VideoView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video);

String path = getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/movie.mp4";
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
video.start();
```

Comment: I have to wait 3 hours for that. Sorry.

Comment: Ok. I was not aware of that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. The `MediaPlayer` object used by the `VideoView` requires the file to be [world-readable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)). Internal files aren't. It is also useless to pass the source with a `Uri` like `file:///`: if so, at the end the MediaPlayer will use its [`setDataSource(String path)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)) method

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42271134/1507512) also on the same argument.